# How to use pen-drive for testing self-made bootloader?

Tags: assembly, x86, boot, bootloader, dd

I've been working on an OS project with my friend. We are following this [Broken Thorn tutorial](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDevIndex.html). We are using Kali Linux to build our OS. Currently we are using *QEMU* PC emulator to test our boot loader.

This is our bootloader file `Boot1.asm`

```
;*********************************************
;   Boot1.asm
;       - A Simple Bootloader
;
;   Operating Systems Development Tutorial
;*********************************************

bits    16                          ; We are still in 16 bit Real Mode

org     0x7c00                      ; We are loaded by BIOS at 0x7C00

start:          jmp loader                  ; jump over OEM block

;*************************************************;
;   OEM Parameter block
;*************************************************;

; Error Fix 2 - Removing the ugly TIMES directive -------------------------------------

;;  TIMES 0Bh-$+start DB 0                  ; The OEM Parameter Block is exactally 3 bytes
                                ; from where we are loaded at. This fills in those
                                ; 3 bytes, along with 8 more. Why?

bpbOEM          db "My OS   "               ; This member must be exactally 8 bytes. It is just
                                ; the name of your OS :) Everything else remains the same.

bpbBytesPerSector:      DW 512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:   DB 1
bpbReservedSectors:     DW 1
bpbNumberOfFATs:        DB 2
bpbRootEntries:         DW 224
bpbTotalSectors:        DW 2880
bpbMedia:               DB 0xF0
bpbSectorsPerFAT:       DW 9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:     DW 18
bpbHeadsPerCylinder:    DW 2
bpbHiddenSectors:       DD 0
bpbTotalSectorsBig:     DD 0
bsDriveNumber:          DB 0
bsUnused:               DB 0
bsExtBootSignature:     DB 0x29
bsSerialNumber:         DD 0xa0a1a2a3
bsVolumeLabel:          DB "MOS FLOPPY "
bsFileSystem:           DB "FAT12   "

msg db  "Welcome to My Operating System!", 0        ; the string to print

;***************************************
;   Prints a string
;   DS=>SI: 0 terminated string
;***************************************

Print:
            lodsb                   ; load next byte from string from SI to AL
            or          al, al      ; Does AL=0?
            jz          PrintDone   ; Yep, null terminator found-bail out
            mov         ah, 0eh ; Nope-Print the character
            int         10h
            jmp         Print       ; Repeat until null terminator found
PrintDone:
            ret                 ; we are done, so return

;*************************************************;
;   Bootloader Entry Point
;*************************************************;

loader:

    xor ax, ax      ; Setup segments to insure they are 0. Remember that
    mov ds, ax      ; we have ORG 0x7c00. This means all addresses are based
    mov es, ax      ; from 0x7c00:0. Because the data segments are within the same
                ; code segment, null em.

    mov si, msg                     ; our message to print
    call    Print                       ; call our print function

    xor ax, ax                      ; clear ax
    int 0x12                        ; get the amount of KB from the BIOS

    cli                         ; Clear all Interrupts
    hlt                         ; halt the system

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0                     ; We have to be 512 bytes. Clear the rest of the bytes with 0

dw 0xAA55                           ; Boot Signiture
```

To compile our boot loaders and test it with *QEMU* we use these commands:

```
nasm -f bin -o Boot1.bin Boot1.asm
dd if=Boot1.bin of=floppyImage.flp bs=512 count=1
qemu-system-x86_64 floppyImage.flp
```

We want to use our pen-drive to test the above code on a real PC. We have available an old useless Desktop PC that has been collecting dust. How do we do it? We tried changing the dd command to the following:

```
dd if=Boot1.bin of=/dev/sdc1 bs=512 count=1
```

Unfortunately this failed.

What is wrong, and how can we solve this problem?

Comment: `of=/dev/sdc1` would put Boot1.bin in the first 512 bytes of the first partition.How about `of=/dev/sdc` for the first 512 bytes of the drive?

Comment: You really should put a `NOP` right after the `jmp loader` because some BIOSes(and software) will expect that BPB to start at the 4th byte. `jmp loader` is a 2 byte instruction. Adding a `nop` (one byte instruction) will push the BPB to the 4th byte. Your BPB as is starts at the 3rd byte of your boot loader. Anything that starts the BPB at the 4th byte in the loader would suffice.

Comment: A more generic way of doing what I suggested in the last comment doesn't require knowledge of the `jmp` instruction size. Remove the `nop` instruction I suggested and use a line like `TIMES 3-($-start) DB 0` after `jmp loader` to align the BPB so it starts at the 4th byte.

Comment: thanks guys for your efforts, i got it finally answer is "boot loader should start with a valid x86 instruction" !

Answer (score -1):

For future references, i'm answering my own question:

```
;*********************************************
;   Boot1.asm
;       - A Simple Bootloader
;
;   Operating Systems Development Tutorial
;*********************************************

bits    16                          ; We are still in 16 bit Real Mode

org     0x7c00  ; We are loaded by BIOS at 0x7C00

jmp start                       ;FAT file system boot loader should start with a valid x86 instruction.
                                ;It is Generally a JUMP instruction at offset 0x00 and acquires 3 bytes.
                                ;or a JUMP SHORT followed by a NOP.


start:          jmp loader                  ; jump over OEM block

;*************************************************;
;   OEM Parameter block
;*************************************************;

; Error Fix 2 - Removing the ugly TIMES directive -------------------------------------

;;  TIMES 0Bh-$+start DB 0                  ; The OEM Parameter Block is exactally 3 bytes
                                ; from where we are loaded at. This fills in those
                                ; 3 bytes, along with 8 more. Why?

bpbOEM          db "My OS   "               ; This member must be exactally 8 bytes. It is just
                                ; the name of your OS :) Everything else remains the same.

bpbBytesPerSector:      DW 512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:   DB 1
bpbReservedSectors:     DW 1
bpbNumberOfFATs:        DB 2
bpbRootEntries:         DW 224
bpbTotalSectors:        DW 2880
bpbMedia:               DB 0xF0
bpbSectorsPerFAT:       DW 9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:     DW 18
bpbHeadsPerCylinder:    DW 2
bpbHiddenSectors:       DD 0
bpbTotalSectorsBig:     DD 0
bsDriveNumber:          DB 0
bsUnused:               DB 0
bsExtBootSignature:     DB 0x29
bsSerialNumber:         DD 0xa0a1a2a3
bsVolumeLabel:          DB "MOS FLOPPY "
bsFileSystem:           DB "FAT12   "

msg db  "Welcome to My Operating System!", 0        ; the string to print

;***************************************
;   Prints a string
;   DS=>SI: 0 terminated string
;***************************************

Print:
            lodsb                   ; load next byte from string from SI to AL
            or          al, al      ; Does AL=0?
            jz          PrintDone   ; Yep, null terminator found-bail out
            mov         ah, 0eh ; Nope-Print the character
            int         10h
            jmp         Print       ; Repeat until null terminator found
PrintDone:
            ret                 ; we are done, so return

;*************************************************;
;   Bootloader Entry Point
;*************************************************;

loader:

    xor ax, ax      ; Setup segments to insure they are 0. Remember that
    mov ds, ax      ; we have ORG 0x7c00. This means all addresses are based
    mov es, ax      ; from 0x7c00:0. Because the data segments are within the same
                ; code segment, null em.

    mov si, msg                     ; our message to print
    call    Print                       ; call our print function

    xor ax, ax                      ; clear ax
    int 0x12                        ; get the amount of KB from the BIOS

    cli                         ; Clear all Interrupts
    hlt                         ; halt the system

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0                     ; We have to be 512 bytes. Clear the rest of the bytes with 0

dw 0xAA55                           ; Boot Signiture
```

the above modified code fixes this problem, with the following dd command:

```
dd if=Boot1.bin of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512 count=1
```

Comment: This is wrong. It just happens to work for you on your hardware. `start: jmp loader` already **IS** a valid instruction and jumps over your BPB. Your code in this answer actually pushes the BPB to the 5th byte of the bootloader because `jmp start` is 2 bytes, and `start:jmp loader` is 2 bytes (4 bytes total) - which does the incorrect thing. All you needed to do is put a `NOP` (1 byte instruction) after `start:jmp loader` and get rid of `jmp start`. That means the BPB which is defined right after will start at the 4th byte in your bootloader (which would be 0x7c03 in physical memory)